# Should/How to edit file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf Disable Touchscreen

Tags: xorg, suspend, touchscreen

I have a broken touchscreen that goes crazy when enabled.

Should I add Option "Ignore" "on" to the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf file?

```
    Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev" 
    **Option "Ignore" "on"**
    EndSection
```

Why cant I just change MatchIsTouchscreen to "off" ???????????????

I have read on a lot of threads that suggest add Option "Ignore" "on". One thread said editing the configuration file can "...blow up xserver!" Is there any truth to that?

If editing this file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf is ok, what is the best method?

```
   1) sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf 
   2) sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
   3) from files simply follow path to -evdev.conf file and edit and save
```

I currently run xinput disable "ELAN Touchscreen" in my startup applications, but when my laptop wakes from suspend the touchscreen is enabled. So I either reboot, or struggle to run the command in the terminal; which is a real challenge sometimes when the screen is going crazy.

I know this question has been asked a number of times but I imagine others must be as confused as I am.

Comment: (1) is fine (2) only if you add the `-H` option for the reasons described in [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/a/270019/178692) (3) you won't have permission to save, unless you run `files` (i.e. `nautilus`) with elevated privileges.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the result will be if I change MatchIsTouchscreen "on" to "off"?  would that do the trick?

Comment: No idea - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited file the file with

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
```

Changed MatchIsTouchscreen from "on" to "off"

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "off"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        EndSection
```

"ELAN touchscreen" is disabled and no longer detected in xinput list.